# Kelly Criterion for Multiple Simultaneous Correlated Bets

Tags: correlation, modern-portfolio-theory, kelly-criterion, betting

I am looking for an equation for the optimal fractional bet sizing for N number of simultaneous correlated bets.

I am looking specifically for an equation for binary bets, but an equation for bets with distributional profit and loss outcomes would be welcome as well.

Comment: Can you tell us about what you came across in your own research and why they did not work for you?

Comment: Kelly Criterion for a single or even multiple independent binary bets is easy to find, however; I can't really find anything regarding specifically what I asked for.

Answer (score 2):

A natural question which was likely studied in academic literature (even though Kelly is not particularly popular among portfolio managers).  I guess you could generalize Eq. (6.87) of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119821320).  If $f(R)$ is the joint probability density of the returns of your $N$ assets (so $R$ is $N$-dimensional vector), for example Gaussian,
$$
f(R)\propto\exp(-(1/2)\sum_{ij}C^{-1}_{ij}(R_i-\mu_i)(R_j-\mu_j)),
$$
and $x$ is an $N$-dimensional vector of your bets, the Kelly log utility is
$$
U(x)=\int\log(1 + x\cdot R)f(R)dR.
$$
The utility is maximized when $\partial U/\partial x_i=0$, or
$$
0 = \int\frac{R_i}{1+x\cdot R}f(R)dR.
$$
I don't know if this can be solved in a closed form, but maximizing $U(x)$ numerically seems doable.  Note that in the classical Kelly case you need to consider only the slab are $0\le\sum_ix_i\le1$, but if you are long/short and levered, the constraint is lifted.